# How is RoboForm or AutoFill identifying text boxes in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to replicate a basic version of RoboForm https://help.roboform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042538712-How-to-use-AutoSave-and-Inplace-AutoFill) or Autofill https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en) chrome extensions and I want to fill out the form here (https://stripe.com/jobs/listing/account-executive-baas/4954092/apply). The main problem is that the stripe form makes use of an iframe to render the text boxes. As such, I am unable to actively get and set the values of the textboxes unless I do a manual inspection to render the iframe which provides me with the iframe textbox ids. RoboForm and AutoFill seem to have access to the id values of the text boxes without having to do anything unique here. See the screenshot attached ([Screenshot of AutoFill Filling Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh390.png)) which shows how Roboform gets the id of the textbox to be able to overlay their icon on the text and also autofill immediately filled out the view once I opened the link on Chrome without me having to reload iframe or inspect any element on iframe

I tried making use of all the basic approaches to query an iframe,

```
document.querySelectorAll('input, iframe'); // to get the iframe id I want 
document.getElementById('grnhse_iframe'); // get the iframe element 
document.getElementById('grnhse_iframe').contentWindow.document; // to get iframe document but I had the error
```

`198:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://stripe.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.at <anonymous>:1:55`

I know this error message is due to the Same-Origin Policy which is a security measure that prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain or accessing the content of a frame from a different domain.

So as a workaround, I used XAMPP and PHP to create a proxy server where I had the code below

`<?php $url = $_GET['url']; $response = file_get_contents($url); echo $response; ?>`
and
tried setting the src of the iframe to `http://localhost/iframe_proxy/index.php?${targetUrl}`
where targetUrl was the src in the iframe I obtained from document.getElementById('grnhse_iframe'). Setting the URL kept giving me
[Report Only] Refused to frame ..."
[Screenshot of Error when i try to set the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2w3u.png)

My suspicion is that RoboForm and AutoFill are doing a different rendering of the iframe that I don't know of, and will appreciate any help here. Since they are able to do it, I believe there should be a way for me to be able to get the textbox and fill it without having to inspect elements manually.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has read the above and is looking for a suggestion, it seems to me that if you are writing a script for auto login, just a suggestion but as a long term roboform user, roboform seems to be able to read and save form details with no issue on a page that has an iframe, I think the filling of it may be linked to the url roboform is trying to fill. Lets say your iframe page is index.php and it calls info_form.php into the iframe. roboform has two url's save a goto url, and a match url, with an iframe these will be two different urls causing roboform to reject the form filling because the do not match, I created a login for one of my iframe forms for an example. so your code will have to check and possible find a way of matching the two.[image]